# Angular 4 Communication between the components not working

Tags: angular, typescript, angular-components

i am unable to communicate between the two components:

I have 2 components one for saving the username and email (please see screenshot) and another one to show the added users.
[image: Components]

First component:

**Adduser**:

```
@Component({
  selector: 'app-adduser',
  templateUrl: './adduser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./adduser.component.css']
})




export class AdduserComponent implements OnInit {
  @Output('users') users = new EventEmitter<any[]>();
  listOfUsers: Array<{username:string,email:string}>=[];
 username:string="";
 email:string="";
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  addedUser(event:Event){
    console.log('emitUser event is called');
    this.users.emit(this.listOfUsers);
  }

  addUser(){
  this.listOfUsers.push( {username:this.username,email:this.email});
  }

  processUser(){

  }
}
```

HTML code for first component:

```html
 <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput">Username</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="username">
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="formGroupExampleInput2">Email</label>
    <input type="text" class="form-control" [(ngModel)]="email">
  </div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="username=== '' || email ===''" (click)="addUser()">AddUser</button> 
<div class="divider"></div>
```

2nd component-> processuser

ts file

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-processuser',
  templateUrl: './processuser.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./processuser.component.css']
})
export class ProcessuserComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input()users:Array<{username:string,email:string}>=[];
  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

}
```

html code for 2nd component :

```html
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" [disabled]="username=== '' || email ===''" (click)="processUser()">ShowUsers</button>
<div class="alert alert-info" role="alert" *ngFor="let user of users ">
  <strong>user.username </strong> <strong>user.email </strong> has been processed.
</div>
```

And the main app component where i am using both of them :

```html
<div class="container">
  <app-adduser (users)="addedUser($event)"></app-adduser>
  <app-processuser [users]=""></app-processuser>
</div>
```

My problems/Doubts:

1. First component Adduser is adding the formdata to array but how will it be emitted ? Debug point is not hitting the emit code.
2. Can i directly pass the data from first component to second one in app.component.html file ? or do i need to process it first in app.component.ts file ?

Please note i am new to Angular.

Any advice would be helpful.

Comment: There is an entire guide dedicated to component interaction https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction

Comment: You never emit anything from your output: the addedUser method is never called anywhere. You need to amit when addUser() is called, after you've added the new user. And you haven't posted the code of the app component, so we have no idea what its addedUser method does. And you don't pass anything as input to the processuser component: `[users]=""`. In short, you need to read the documentation on inputs and outputs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Angular has top to bottom data flow approach. It means that the child gets from parent via input and if the child has to tell something to the parent  , then it has to emit what it want to tell explicitly

```
<parent-component>
  <child-component (tellParent)="tellParent($event)" [giveToChild]="giveToChild"> 
  </child-component>
</parent-component>
```

> parent.component.ts : Parent Gives to child toffee via input or square brackets[ ]

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'parent-component',
  templateUrl: './parent-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./parent-component.css']
})
export class ParentComponent implements OnInit {

  giveToChild:string = 'Toffee';

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {
  }

  tellParent(childResponse){
     console.log(childResponse) // "Thanks dada and mama"
  }

}
```

> child.component.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit,Input } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'Child-component',
  templateUrl: './Child-component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./Child-component.css']
})
export class ChildComponent implements OnInit {

  @Input() giveToChild:string
  @Output() tellParent = new EventEmitter<any>();

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit() {

  }
  tellParentFunc(){
    this.tellParent.emit("Thanks dada and mama")
  }
```

Answer (score 1):

Main template:

```
<parent>
   <child (messageToParent) ="receiveMessageFromChild($event)"></child>
</parent>
```

Child component:

```
@Output() messageToParent : EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter();

sendMessageToParent() 
{ 
   this.messageToParent.emit("message from child"); 
}
```

Parent component:

```
receiveMessageFromChild(message) 
{
   console.log(message); // Console reads : "message from child"
}
```